# Вывести массив JSON после AJAX запроса

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Вот JS

```
$(".btn").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    url: "mail.php",
    method: 'post',
    data: {
      index: "1"
    },
    success: function (response) {
     console.log(response);
    },
    error: function(){
     alert('Ошибка при отправке');
    }
  });
```

Вот PHP из mail.php

```
if(isset($_POST['index'])) {
    $index = strip_tags($_POST['index']);
    if($index == "1") {
        $name = "Den";
        $age = "30";
    }
}
```

Как в переменную response передать данные $name и $age в виде JSON массива?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создаете ассоциативный массив с вашими данными, кодируете в json и выводите.

Пример:

```
if(isset($_POST['index'])) {
    $index = strip_tags($_POST['index']);
    if($index == "1") {
        $res = array(
            'name' => 'Den',
            'age' => '30'
        );
        echo json_encode($res);
        die();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Использовать **[json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode.php)**  для преобразования массива в json. А отдачей в output будет заниматься `echo`

```
echo json_encode(['name' => $name, 'age' => $age]);
exit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Дополнительно рекомендовал бы передавать флаг JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE, если нужно не кодировать многобайтовые символы Unicode

```
echo json_encode($res, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```